# Chameleon + Cloud of Darkness

Tags: dnd-4e, stealth, immediate-actions

My question is about the interaction between the Rogue Utility Chameleon (below and PHB 120) and the Drow racial Cloud of Darkness.

> #### Chameleon (Rogue Utility 6)
>
> *You blend into your surroundings.*
> **At-Will [image] Martial**
> **Immediate Interrupt**, **Personal**
> **Prerequisite:** You must have training in Stealth.
> **Trigger:** You are hidden and lose cover or concealment against an enemy.
> **Effect:** You make a Stealth check. If your check beats the triggering enemy’s passive Perception, you remain hidden from it, and until the end of your next turn you can remain hidden from it without needing any cover or concealment.

> #### Cloud of Darkness (Drow Racial Power)
>
> *A shroud of blackness descends around you, hiding you from sight.*
> **Encounter**
> **Minor Action**, **Close burst** 1
> **Effect:** The burst creates a cloud of darkness that remains in place until the end of your next turn. The cloud blocks line of sight, squares within it are totally obscured, and creatures entirely within it are blinded until they exit. You are immune to these effects.

In short: Chameleon allows a Rogue to make a stealth check if he loses concealment or cover on someone else's turn (say an enemy comes around a corner).  Cloud of Darkness heavily obscures affected squares and lasts until the end of the Drow's *next* turn.  My question is this:

**Rogue's turn 1:** Minor action to drop cloud, shift 0 and make a stealth check to gain hidden.

**Rogue's turn 2:** Cloud is still around.  Make attack from hidden, shift 0 and gain hidden again.  At the *end of this turn*, Cloud disappears and the Rogue loses concealment.  **Can the Rogue use Chameleon to regain hidden?**

I am completely unsure as to how the timing of "end of turn" works with immediate actions, which *cannot* be used on your own turn.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the formatting help, BESW.  I tried to figure out how to do that and couldn't.

Comment: @uscere Out of curiousity, why are you shifting 0?

Comment: @JonathanHobbs expenditure of a move action to be able to roll stealth.

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

The "end of your next turn" phase is still part of your turn and for sure it is not part of another creature's turn.

> ### [Immediate Action](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=120)<sup>DDI</sup>
>
> There are two kinds of immediate actions: interrupts and reactions. The following rules govern both kinds of immediate action.
>
> **Trigger:** Each immediate action—usually a power—defines its trigger. The one type of immediate action that every creature can take is a readied action (see “Ready an Action”.
>
> **Someone Else’s Turn:** A creature cannot take an immediate action on its own turn. The action interrupts some event on another creature’s turn or responds to that event.
>
> *[...]*

The last quoted paragraph implies that no event can take place between two creatures' turns: it either takes place in your turn or in another creature's turn.

[Cloud of Darkness](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=2473)<sup>DDI</sup> ends naturally in the end of turn phase of your turn and thus is not a viable trigger for [Chameleon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1506)<sup>DDI</sup>.